# Problema con $HTTP_RAW_POST

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, vue.js

Buen día. 
 Estaba haciendo una conexión Vue.js con Axios y Laravel y noté este problema. 
1. Agregué un método y quería mostrar el elemento por consola.

```
  methods: {
        newThought(){
            const params = {
                description: this.description
            }
            axios.post('/thoughts', params).then((Response) => console.log(Response));

            this.$emit('new', thought);
            this.$description = '';
        }
    }
```

Lo revisé en el buscador en la pestaña Network y salió la siguiente línea

> **Deprecated**: Automatically populating $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA is deprecated and will be removed in a future version. To avoid this warning set 'always_populate_raw_post_data' to '-1' in php.ini and use the php://input stream instead. in Unknown on line 0
>
> **Warning**: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent in Unknown on line 0
>   {"description":"Pensamiento","user_id":1,"updated_at":"2018-05-29 11:22:55","created_at":"2018-05-29 11:22:55","id":2}

esos mismos datos salen en lugar de la Data que esperaba.

Estoy usando Wamp. Dejo la repo de github por si el problema requiere saber si hago otra cosa mal.

https://github.com/Cragser/exCRUD-laravel-vue-7

Comment: `$HTTP_RAW_POST` fue declarada obsoleta y eliminada en PHP7 en su lugar se deberia utilizar el flujo  `php://input` mas info aqui: http://php.net/manual/es/wrappers.php.php#wrappers.php.input  | En cualquier caso, seria recomendable que añadas el codigo implicado a la pregunta para que podamos ayudarte.

Comment: Agregué el código en github, y la petición que hago por axios, ¿será eso suficiente o tengo que hacer otra cosa?

Comment: Como comprenderas no vamos a revisar todo el codigo de tu proyecto, dejanos aqui los metodos del controlado implicados, editando la pregunta y añadiendo el codigo

Answer (score 0):

> Deprecated: Automatically populating $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA is deprecated
>   and will be removed in a future version. To avoid this warning set
>   'always_populate_raw_post_data' to '-1' in php.ini and use the
>   php://input stream instead. in Unknown on line 0
>
> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent in
>   Unknown on line 0
>   {"description":"Pensamiento","user_id":1,"updated_at":"2018-05-29
>   11:22:55","created_at":"2018-05-29 11:22:55","id":2}

Después de hacer mi investigación, notifico que el error fue causado por WAMP, un problema directamente del servidor local que usé. La solución más viable que tuve en ese momento fue cambiar a una alternativa llamada Laragon, en el cual me funcionó de maravilla.

Pero puede intentar cambiar la configuración de PHP.ini y directamente la configuración del host en windows; sin embargo, lo ideal a mi punto de vista es que si tienen este error lo prueben en una máquina virtual primero con una distro de linux.

Buen día.